# Fastest way to iterate through a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, pandas, ipython

How do I run through a dataframe and return only the rows which meet a certain condition? This condition has to be tested on previous rows and columns. For example:

```
          #1    #2    #3    #4
1/1/1999   4     2     4     5
1/2/1999   5     2     3     3
1/3/1999   5     2     3     8
1/4/1999   6     4     2     6
1/5/1999   8     3     4     7
1/6/1999   3     2     3     8
1/7/1999   1     3     4     1
```

I could like to test a few conditions for each row and if all conditions are passed I would like to append the row to list. For example:

```
for row in dataframe:
    if [row-1, column 0] + [row-2, column 3] >= 6:
        append row to a list
```

I may have up to 3 conditions which must be true for the row to be returned. The way 
am thinking about doing it is by making a list for all the observations which are true
for each condition, and then making a separate list for all of the rows that appear in all three lists.

My two questions are the following:

What is the fastest way to get all of the rows that meet a certain condition based on previous rows? Looping through a dataframe of 5,000 rows seems like it may be too long. Especially if potentially 3 conditions have to be tested.

What is the best way to get a list of rows which meet all 3 conditions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest way to select rows is to *not* iterate through the rows of the dataframe. Instead, create a mask (boolean array) with True values for the rows you wish to select, and then call `df[mask]` to select them:

```
mask = (df['column 0'].shift(1) + df['column 3'].shift(2) >= 6)
newdf = df[mask]
```

---

To combine more than one condition with logical-and, use `&`:

```
mask = ((...) & (...))
```

For logical-or use `|`:

```
mask = ((...) | (...))
```

---

For example,

```
In [75]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5), 'B':range(10,20,2)})

In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
   A   B
0  0  10
1  1  12
2  2  14
3  3  16
4  4  18

In [77]: mask = (df['A'].shift(1) + df['B'].shift(2) > 12)

In [78]: mask
Out[78]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool

In [79]: df[mask]
Out[79]: 
   A   B
3  3  16
4  4  18
```

Comment: @unutbu Why are you using .shift(1) and .shift(2) here?

Comment: @VatsalAggarwal: The OP wrote `if [row-1, column 0] + [row-2, column 3] >= 6` where `row-1` signified the previous row and `row-2` signified the row preceding the previous row. Translated into Pandas-speak, that's `df['A'].shift(1)` and `df['B'].shift(2)`.

Comment: @unutbu Thank you! For this explanation